# How to add click listener to selected mkannotationview?

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I need to click on annotation on the map. I can see selected annotation view like this [image: mkannotationview]

I want to add click listener on this selected annotation view to open another view controller with annotation's details. How can I do this?

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let selected = (view.annotation as? CustomAnnotation) {
        self.selectedAnnotation = selected
    }
}
```

**Edited**

Comment: I want to add click listener to mkannotationview to open 2nd view controller, where I pass data from selected annotation.

Comment: how can I add click to mkannotation view, when annotation is selected?

Comment: I know about rightCalloutAccessoryView, but I need to make the whole callout clickable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you’d add, for example, a `rightCalloutAccessoryView` and then implement `calloutAccessoryControlTapped`, like shown in [how do I make a pin annotation callout?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33978778/1271826)

But you say:

> I need to make the whole callout clickable

MapKit doesn’t have a delegate method to capture taps on the callout, itself, only on the accessory views. But you can add your own delegate to do this for you.

```
protocol CustomAnnotationViewDelegate: class {
    func didTapCallout(for annotation: MKAnnotation)
}

class CustomAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
    static let preferredReuseIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".customAnnotationView"

    weak var delegate: CustomAnnotationViewDelegate?

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        canShowCallout = true

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapAnnotationView(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @objc func didTapAnnotationView(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let location = gesture.location(in: self)

        // ignore taps on the annotation view, itself

        if bounds.contains(location) { return }

        // if we got here, we must have tapped on the callout

        delegate?.didTapCallout(for: annotation!)
    }
}
```

Then in iOS 11 and later, you can register this reuseIdentifier:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.register(CustomAnnotationView.self,
                     forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: CustomAnnotationView.preferredReuseIdentifier)
}
```

And your `viewFor` could specify the delegate:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier, for: annotation) as! CustomAnnotationView
        annotationView.delegate = self
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Or, if you need to support iOS versions prior to 11, you wouldn’t register the reuse identifier but would have to manually instantiate the `CustomAnnotationView` yourself if it is not successfully dequeued:

```
extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: CustomAnnotationView.preferredReuseIdentifier) as? CustomAnnotationView
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: CustomAnnotationView.preferredReuseIdentifier)
            annotationView?.delegate = self
        } else {
            annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        return annotationView
    }
}
```

Either way, you can now have your view controller conform to the new `CustomAnnotationViewDelegate`:

```
extension ViewController: CustomAnnotationViewDelegate {
    func didTapCallout(for annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        print("tapped callout for \(annotation)")
    }
}
```

But note that in the above, I’m adding the tap gesture recognizer in the `CustomAnnotationView` `init` method, to ensure that the tap gesture is created once and only once, when the annotation view is first created.